# Reliable tool to obtain all dns records

Tags: dns

I have a domain that I own and have access to via the company I purchased it from.  However it's DNS configuration is not hosted with this company but off site with someone else where it used to be hosted.

This other company is incredibly slow to deal with and don't have a web based solution to manage their DNS entries.

I now need to make a change to the DNS and fed-up waiting on this third party want to set my domain to not use an external DNS and have all its properties defined on company that it's registered to.

I need a tool that can read all the basic records of the DNS (`A`, `CNAME`, `TXT`, `MX`) and display these simply so I can be confident when re-defining all the entries that I'm not missing anything.   I know that at various points I had `TXT` records to assist with spam prevention setup and my email is hosted externally so its important I get a copy of all these entries.

I've seen websites that do this to a degree but they usually make you do various searches for each record type and the information presented is often very verbose.   Anyone have any recommended tools either cmd line or online ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many command line tools, you would just need to do a loop on the record types you need around them.

Some examples: `nslookup`, `dig` (start here if you do not know what to do), `drill`.

You have also web interfaces on top of them, like https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/ for `dig`.

You also have many tools online doing the same thing. See for example "DNS report" at http://www.viewdns.info/

In all cases however you need to be careful to know which nameservers are queried. You should do your investigations by querying the authoritative nameservers of your domain, not some recursive ones.